# It is possible to vertical scroll as ViewGroup in android using TV remote navigation

Tags: android, android-tv, epg

1.What steps I will reproduce the problem?

2.I am Developing an android application as Electronic Program Guide(EPG) for set-top-box followed by this project https://github.com/codessentials/android-tv-epg."

3.I can able to navigate left to right,rigtht to left(Horizontal scroll) & able to see the focus also(Left & right Remote DPAD-Key Navigation).

4.Here,i used vertical scroll as,

Scroller mScroller=new Scroller(context);

mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(),getScrollY(),0, -150, 5);

5.While vertical scrolling time the  scroll view size is increased automatically & view is changed in top position.

6.I am getting this output ...[image]

7.I want to show few channel for each  vertical scroll(DPAD-UP & DPAD-DOWN) But do not stretched the design(UI).

8. How to scroll without stretched the design?,please advice it, how to solve this?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

you can  add these line under DPAD event and you will get your desire result

**DPAD-UP**

mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), 0, -200, 600);

//you can chnage DY,DX value and also duration

**DPAD-DOWN**

mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), 0, 200, 600);

//you can chanage DY,DX value and also duration